# What is the issue with using the nant script to run msbuild to register the assembly?

Tags: msbuild, nant, com-interop, regasm

I'm running MSBuild from a NAnt script.  When it tries to register one of my assemblies for `com interop`, the script stops like it's stuck.

If I run `regasm.exe` on the assembly, it succeeds.  Even if I run MSBuild itself from the command-line with the exact same parameters, it builds successfully.

What is the problem with using the NAnt script to run MSBuild to register the assembly?  Could it be permissions?

Comment: Are you using the exec task to call msbuild or are you using the msbuild task (part of NAntContrib)?

Comment: can you provide a verbose build log?

Comment: Can you post the part of the nant script that invokes this?